# Error building mongodb from sources

Tags: c++, mongodb, gcc

I'm trying to build mongodb from sources and getting a number of errors.

Here's the pastebin of the whole output:
http://pastebin.com/pyZLTkz4

The first error is

```
endian.h does not define __BYTE_ORDER nor BYTE_ORDER. Cannot determine endianness.
```

And all other errors are like

```
error: template with C linkage
error: template specialization with C linkage
```

My configuration is:

1. **Debian 8 64 bit**
2. scons version: **2.3.1**
3. python version: **2 7 9**
4. gcc version: **gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2**

Installed dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mongodb
```

I have tried to build it under CentOS 7 and had the same result.

Comment: I just ran into this same error in 2017, did you ever resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening while building the embedded SpiderMonkey engine ("mozjs" - Mozilla JavaScript, version 38).

As you're using a VERBOSE=1 build in SCONS, you're seeing that an include directory is added via the `-I` switch to compile with `-Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/mfbt`.  Because of the very aggressive behavior of `-I`, this means any include files in that directory will pre-empt any system include files of the same name.

*(For why `-I` acts this way, see ["Why do projects use the -I include switch given the dangers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154898/).  I'll add for Google crawlers that builds circa 2018 use SpiderMonkey 45, so the directory is `-Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-45/extract/mfbt`)*

So what's happening is that the `mfbt/Endian.h` file (which brings in a bunch of high-level C++ definitions) is overriding your system's low-level `/usr/include/endian.h` file, which is wreaking havoc when anyone tries to `#include <endian.h>` to get the system definitions.

The question you likely have is **why is it only happening to you**...and a few others.

I'm going to guess the reason is probably the same as in my case, which led me to this question: your MongoDB source files are on a filesystem that is retrieving them case-insensitively.  So perhaps you are running a Debian Linux VM but have your files on a Windows host.

Most people building on Linux are using fully case-sensitive filesystems, that wouldn't have an `Endian.h` considered as a candidate to override their system's `endian.h`.  So their builds succeed.

---

If you are running a version of Windows 10 since the April 2018 update, and [have the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/977) enabled, then you can set specific Windows directories to be case-sensitive, e.g.

> fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo C:\Projects\mongo\src\third_party\mozjs-45\extract\mfbt enable

Unfortunately, it's something you have to set up on each individual folder...you can't do it for entire subtrees.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

About first error

The sys/param.h header normally defines the symbols __BYTE_ORDER, __BIG_ENDIAN, __LITTLE_ENDIAN, and __PDP_ENDIAN. You can test endianness by doing something like:

The sys/param.h header normally defines the symbols __BYTE_ORDER, __BIG_ENDIAN, __LITTLE_ENDIAN, and __PDP_ENDIAN. You can test endianness by doing something like:

```
   #include <sys/param.h>

   #ifdef __BYTE_ORDER
   # if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
   #  define I_AM_LITTLE_ENDIAN
   # else
   #  if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
   #   define I_AM_BIG_ENDIAN
   #  else
       Error: unknown byte order!
   #  endif
   # endif
   #endif /* __BYTE_ORDER */
```

If __BYTE_ORDER is not defined, you may want to test for the existance of BYTE_ORDER, BIG_ENDIAN and LITTLE_ENDIAN. Linux defines these as synonym of the versions with underscores, apparantly in attempt to be compatible with BSD Unix.

If that is not defined, you might try things like:

```
   #if defined (i386) || defined (__i386__) || defined (_M_IX86) || \
        defined (vax) || defined (__alpha)
   # define I_AM_LITTLE_ENDIAN
   #endif
```

[Read more](http://unixpapa.com/incnote/byteorder.html)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

A. You're missing the glibc development headers.

Try installing libc6-dev (debian) or glibc-headers (redhat)

B. You have a non-standard endian.h floating around on your include path

You could try running:

```
g++ -M -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -std=c++11 -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -O2 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-missing-braces -fno-builtin-memcmp -include js-confdefs.h -Wno-invalid-offsetof -DAB_CD -DIMPL_MFBT -DJS_USE_CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR -DNO_NSPR_10_SUPPORT -DSTATIC_JS_API=1 -DU_NO_DEFAULT_INCLUDE_UTF_HEADERS=1 -DPCRE_STATIC -DBOOST_THREAD_VERSION=4 -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_VARIADIC_THREAD -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_INTERRUPTIONS -DBOOST_THREAD_HAS_NO_EINTR_BUG -Isrc -Ibuild/opt -Isrc -Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/js/src -Isrc/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/js/src -Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/mfbt -Isrc/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/mfbt -Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/intl/icu/source/common -Isrc/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/intl/icu/source/common -Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/include -Isrc/third_party/mozjs-38/include -Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/mongo_sources -Isrc/third_party/mozjs-38/mongo_sources -Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/platform/x86_64/linux/build -Isrc/third_party/mozjs-38/platform/x86_64/linux/build -Ibuild/opt/third_party/mozjs-38/platform/x86_64/linux/include -Isrc/third_party/mozjs-38/platform/x86_64/linux/include -Isrc/third_party/zlib-1.2.8 src/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/js/src/builtin/RegExp.cpp | grep endian.h
```

That's the first compile failure from your pastbin with '-M' substituted for the -o, which should let us see which file you're actually including as endian.h.

Comment: A. I have all headers installed. And I tried to build it on both systems: Debian and CentOS (may be I should try Ubuntu, but I believe it's gonna have same result).

B. Running this gets me same error. That I have same error:

src/third_party/mozjs-38/extract/js/src/jscpucfg.h:71:4: error: #error "endian.h does not define __BYTE_ORDER nor BYTE_ORDER. Cannot determine endianness."